# Elfinder filemanager with multiple buttons updating text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

Each buttons are updating the element:

```
<input type="text" id="field" name="image" value="<?php echo @$DuzenleSonuc[0]['image']; ?>" />
```

I want to update the elements exactly like that:

```
  onclick open -> update field
  onclick open1 -> update field1
  onclick open2 -> update field2
  onclick open3 -> update field3
  onclick open4 -> update field4
```

The situation is now exactly like below. Where am I wrong?

```
  onclick open -> updates field
  onclick open1 -> updates field
  onclick open2 -> updates field
  onclick open3 -> updates field
  onclick open4 -> updates field
```

My code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $().ready(function() {
        var opt = {// Must change variable name
            url : 'elfinder/connectors/php/connector.php',
            lang : 'tr',
            editorCallback : function(url) {document.getElementById('field').value=url;},// Must change the form field id
            closeOnEditorCallback : true,
            docked : false,
            dialog : { title : 'Dosya Yöneticisi', height: 500 },
        }

        $('#open').click(function() {// Must change the button's id
            $('#finder_browse').elfinder(opt)// Must update the form field id
            $('#finder_browse').elfinder($(this).attr('id')); // Must update the form field id
        })

        $('#open1').click(function() {// Must change the button's id
            $('#finder_browse1').elfinder(opt)// Must update the form field id
            $('#finder_browse1').elfinder($(this).attr('id')); // Must update the form field id
        })
        $('#open2').click(function() {// Must change the button's id
            $('#finder_browse2').elfinder(opt)// Must update the form field id
            $('#finder_browse2').elfinder($(this).attr('id')); // Must update the form field id
        })
        $('#open3').click(function() {// Must change the button's id
            $('#finder_browse3').elfinder(opt)// Must update the form field id
            $('#finder_browse3').elfinder($(this).attr('id')); // Must update the form field id
        })
        $('#open4').click(function() {// Must change the button's id
            $('#finder_browse4').elfinder(opt)// Must update the form field id
            $('#finder_browse4').elfinder($(this).attr('id')); // Must update the form field id
        })
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.taslak').click(function(){
            $('#k').val("Taslak");
        });
    })
</script>
<!-- elFinder -->
<div class="textbox left">
    <h2>Ürün Resimleri</h2>

    <div class="textbox_content">
        <p class="fileupload">
            <label>Ürün Ana Resmi:</label>
        <div id="finder_browse"></div>
        <input type="text" id="field" name="image" value="<?php echo @$DuzenleSonuc[0]['image']; ?>" />
        <input type="button" id="open" class="file" value="Resim Seç" />
        </p>
        <hr />
        <p class="fileupload">
            <label>Ürün Resmi:</label>
        <div id="finder_browse1"></div>
        <input type="text" id="field1" name="image1" value="<?php echo @$DuzenleSonuc[0]['image1']; ?>" />
        <input type="button" id="open1" class="file" value="Resim Seç" />
        </p>
        <p class="fileupload">
            <label>Ürün Resmi:</label>
        <div id="finder_browse2"></div>
        <input type="text" id="field2" name="image2" value="<?php echo @$DuzenleSonuc[0]['image2']; ?>" />
        <input type="button" id="open2" class="file" value="Resim Seç" />
        </p>
        <p class="fileupload">
            <label>Ürün Resmi:</label>
        <div id="finder_browse3"></div>
        <input type="text" id="field3" name="image3" value="<?php echo @$DuzenleSonuc[0]['image3']; ?>" />
        <input type="button" id="open3" class="file" value="Resim Seç" />
        </p>
        <p class="fileupload">
            <label>Ürün Resmi:</label>
        <div id="finder_browse4"></div>
        <input type="text" id="field4" name="image4" value="<?php echo @$DuzenleSonuc[0]['image4']; ?>" />
        <input type="button" id="open4" class="file" value="Resim Seç" />
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the same class to all your button and add just one click event something like:

```
$('.btnClass').click(function(){
var btnID = $(this).attr('id'); // Btn id clicked
// Process ckick event
});
```

or if all button have the starting id open you can make a click event like

```
$('input[id^=open]').click(function(){    var btnID = $(this).attr('id'); // Btn id clicked});
```

add after your comment
once you get the btnID you can find which finder-browse to use somethign like:

```
var $browser;
switch(btID)
{
case 'open':
$browser = $('#finder_browse');
break;case 'open1':
$browser = $('#finder_browse1');
break;
```

etc..
}

Comment: I changed the code like that but still have same problem...

 $('#open').click(function() { 
var btnID = $(this).attr('id');// Must change the button's id
$('#finder_browse').elfinder(opt)                // Must update the form field id
                            $('#finder_browse').elfinder($(btnID).attr('id'));   // Must update the form field id
})

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but according to your code you can write something like:
switch(btnID)